# RegEx to replace anything except positive number (no decimals)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a very specific RegEx with the following capabilities:

- Remove any leading zero
- Remove anything that is not a number
- Remove anything after decimal comma or decimal point

Here are some examples:

```
"1,1" => "1"
"1,5" => "1"
"1.1" => "1"
"1.5" => "1"
"-1" => "1"
"a-1" => "1"
"+1" => "1"
"a+1" => "1"
"01" => "1"
"1+1" => "1"
"abc" => ""
"abc1" => "1"
```

The one I was able to construct was not able to handle all my needs:
`/[^0-9].*/g`

Answer (score 1):

Building on @ponury-kostek's observation in a comment on another answer:

```js
function extractPositiveNumber(input) {
    const match = input.match(/0*(\d+)/);
    return match?.[1];  // returns the captured (\d+) or else undefined
}

const testInputs = ['1,1', '1,5', '1.1', '1.5', '-1', 'a-1', '+1', 'a+1', '01', '1+1', 'abc', 'abc1'];

console.log(testInputs.map(extractPositiveNumber));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work:

```
^[0]*(\d+)([,.]\d+)?[^0-9]*$
```

- ^ asserts the start of the string.
- [0]* matches any number of leading zeros.
- (\d+) captures one or more digits.
- ([,.]\d+)? optionally captures a decimal comma or decimal point followed by one or more digits.
- [^0-9]* matches any non-digit characters.
- $ asserts the end of the string.

Comment: You'll need to amend this to handle non-numeric characters at the beginning (e.g. `abc1`) ... perhaps `.*?([1-9]\d*).*` would be more appropriate.

Comment: `[0]*(\d+)` or `([1-9]\d*)`is enough